# Botón de eliminar hecho con Tkinter no cumple con su función

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa con pycharm/tkinter accediendo a una base de datos para mostrar la información en la aplicación.
El problema es el botón de eliminar, que aunque trato de que elimine el elemento seleccionado, no funciona y no me da error: solo no lo elimina, y me da una revision diciendome "unexpected type", esta revision o inspeccion me aparece en la funcion del_producto justo aqui: "self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())", para ser aun mas especificos aqui: "self.tabla.selection()". A continuación les muestro el código (Porfavor tener en cuenta que no esta completo el codigo, solo puse las partes importantes de la clase y el punto principal del problema que es la funcion del_producto):

```
class Producto:

    tabla: Treeview
    db = "database/productos.db"

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.ventana = root
        self.ventana.title("App Gestor de Productos")
        self.ventana.resizable(1,1)# Si en lugar de 1,1 ponemos 0,0 la ventana no se puede redimensionar
        self.ventana.wm_iconbitmap("Recursos/hunters_mark1.ico")

        # Creacion del contenedor frame principal
        frame = LabelFrame(self.ventana, text = "Registrar un nuevo Producto")
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 20)
        
        # Label de Nombre
        self.etiqueta_nombre = Label(frame, text="Nombre: ")
        self.etiqueta_nombre.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # Entry Nombre
        self.nombre = Entry(frame)
        self.nombre.focus() # Recordar que esto solo puede tenerlo uno de los entry
        self.nombre.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Label de Precio
        self.etiqueta_precio = Label(frame, text="Precio: ")
        self.etiqueta_precio.grid(row=2, column=0)
        # Entry Precio
        self.precio = Entry(frame)
        self.precio.grid(row=2, column=1)

        # Boton de añadir producto
        self.boton_aniadir = ttk.Button(frame, text = "Guardar Producto", command = self.add_producto) # Muy importante, aqui no se ponen los parentesis
        self.boton_aniadir.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

        # Mensajes de Emergencia
        self.mensaje = Label(text="", fg="red")
        self.mensaje.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

        # Tabla de Productos
        # Estilo Personalizado
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri',11)) # Se modifica la fuente de la tabla
        style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13, 'bold')) # Se modifica la fuente de las cabeceras
        style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky':'nswe'})]) # Eliminamos los bordes

        # Estructura de la Tabla
        self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(frame, height=20, columns=2, style="mystyle.Treeview")
        self.tabla.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.tabla.heading("#0", text="Nombre", anchor=CENTER)
        self.tabla.heading("#1", text="Precio", anchor=CENTER)

        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure("my.TButton", font=("Calibri", 14, "bold"))

        boton_eliminar = ttk.Button(text='ELIMINAR', command= self.del_producto(), style = "my.TButton")
        boton_eliminar.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W + E)

    def del_producto(self):
        print(self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection()))
        nombre = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())["text"]
        query = "DELETE FROM producto WHERE nombre = ?"
        self.db_consulta(query,(nombre,))
        self.get_productos()
```

Comment: Por favor, dale el formato correspondiente al código agregando triples _backticks_ (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código. Como la indentación en Python es crítica, debes hacer tal modificación en tu pregunta por tu cuenta. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: tu function usa self, lo que sugiere que es parte de una clase. Pero en tu codigo la function no esta dentro de ninguna clase. Pon la funcion dentro de una clase para resolver el problema con self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el atributo `command` del botón hay que pasarle una función (siendo precisos, un *método*). Lo que estás pasando es el resultado retornado por el método, `self.del_producto()`, cuando debería ser simplemente `self.del_producto`, sin paréntesis.

En lugar de:

```py
boton_eliminar = ttk.Button(text='ELIMINAR', command= self.del_producto(), style = "my.TButton")
```

debería ser:

```py
boton_eliminar = ttk.Button(text='ELIMINAR', command= self.del_producto, style = "my.TButton")
```

Cuando creas el botón, se llama a `self.del_producto()`. Como no hay nada seleccionado en la tabla, la query SQL no encuentra nada para borrar y, por eso, no hace nada ni sale ningún error. Equivale a `command=None`, que es lo mismo que no tener ninguna acción asignada.